# using a switch function to conditionally render components

Tags: reactjs

updating question because I am still having issues
trying to render components based on a piece of state. I can get the data from the api and console.log the info. But my switch function isn't swapping the components. When I manually update the conditions
such as doing the following:

```
case !this.fetchedweatherdata === false:
```

the app will refresh and show the component. But I can't get it to update based on the state changing? For example, once the form is submitted I want the switch function to pass the information to  component and have it show the information

under my  component this is the switch function

```
 getComponent(props = {} || this.props, state) {
    switch (this.state.weather) {
      case !this.fetchedweatherdata:
        return (
          <DisplayWeather
            currentweather={this.state.currentweather}
            currentforecast={this.state.currentforecast}
            currenttime={this.state.currenttime}
          />
        );

      case !this.hourlyWeather:
        return (
          <DisplayHourlyWeather hourlyWeather={this.state.hourlyWeather} />
        );

      case this.fetchedweatherdata:
        return <Form loadWeather={this.fetchWeatherData} />;

      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```

Also under App 
I trying to render the entire thing using this switch function.

```
 render() {
    const {
      currentforecast,
      currenttime,
      currentweather,
      weatherIcon,
      hourlyWeather
    } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Weather forecast</h1>
       {this.getComponent(this.state)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want the function to be able to update the components themselves.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like you are returning an assignment statement, instead of returning the component. Just return `<DisplayWeather prop={this.currentweather} />`, from the `getComponent()` function

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the arguments of `getComponent` in `{ }` (object destructuring style), but in your render method you call this function with `this.getComponent(this.state)`. You should either change the definition of the function to `getComponent(state)` or call it with `this.getComponent({state: this.state})`